# Torque unable to determine local server hostname

Tags: torque

When I attempt to run "torque.setup" on a vm created in open stack, I get the error "unable to determine local server hostname"

Installing torque on a VM created in any other hypervisor gives no error, and works correctly.

```
[root@cent63 github]# /var/spool/torque/github/torque.setup root
initializing TORQUE (admin: root@cent63)
PBS_Server: LOG_ERROR::pbsd_main, unable to determine local server hostname -     getaddrinfo(cent63) failed, h_errno=1
ERROR: pbs_server failed to start, check syslog and server logs for more information



cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

[root@cent63 github]# hostname
cent63


[root@cent63 github]# service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

The hostname is set, so what is torque complaining about?

```
vim src/server/pbsd_main.c

    snprintf(server_host, PBS_MAXHOSTNAME, "%s", optarg);

    if (get_fullhostname(server_host, server_host, PBS_MAXHOSTNAME, EMsg) == -1)
      {
      /* FAILURE */

      if (EMsg[0] != '\0')
        {
        char tmpLine[1024];

        snprintf(tmpLine, sizeof(tmpLine),
            "unable to determine full hostname for specified server host '%s' - %s",
            server_host, EMsg);

        log_err(-1, __func__, tmpLine);
        }
      else
        {
        log_err(-1, __func__, "unable to determine full server hostname");
        }

      exit(1);
      }
```

*UPDATE*: It looks like I do not have a fully qualified host name.

```
[root@cent63 github]# hostname -f
hostname: Unknown host
```

So far, adding a hostname to  /etc/hosts has not solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
get_fullhostname(server_host, server_host, PBS_MAXHOSTNAME, EMsg)
```

Does the equivalent of hostname -f

I solved it by adding the ip address of the vm to the /etc/hosts file

```
10.2.191.12 cent63
```